# Show Executed Query One at The Time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

source from post:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){  
echo "$key $value<br>";  
}
```

result from souce above:

```
key1 value1  
key2 value2  
key3 value3  
...   
key**n** value**n**
```

because php is server side script. result show at same time.
my goal is to show every line has been execute one at a time.
my idea is use ajax to execute.

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){  
echo"
<script>
$.ajax({ 
    url: "save.php", 
    type: "POST", 
    data: "key="+$key,"value="+$value, 
    dataType: "text", 
    success: function(data){ 
        if (data==1){ 
            $("#result").append("<div><?=$key." and ".$value?> has been saved</div>");
        } 
    }
});
</script>
}
```

what best practice to use ideas above? did i must put ajax foreach item or just call it one time?

Comment: how long does it take for one query to save that you want them appear one by one? several seconds each?

Comment: result is 1000 line more, just to monitor process.

Comment: 1000 inserts is just one second. you will waste more time on monitoring, making 1000 HTTP requests

Comment: you know client, want more style in their program. xD

Comment: Look at my avatar and guess my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Its better store all query ajax in one array ob objects and call it at end:

```
    echo "
    <script>
    var _ajax = [];";
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){  
    echo"
    _ajax.push({
    data: "key="+$key,"value="+$value
    });
    ";
    }
    echo "
    for(var i=0;i<_ajax.length;i++) {
makeCall(_ajax[i]);
}
function makeCall(value){.
$.ajax({ 
        url: "save.php", 
        type: "POST", 
        data: value, 
        dataType: "text", 
        success: function(data){ 
            if (data==1){ 
                $("#result").append("<div><?=$key." and ".$value?> has been saved</div>");
            } 
        }
    });  
}

    }

    </script>";
```

And if you use [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) library for promises, youll do once and more clean.
I changed code for make ajax call inside a function.

Comment: your idea is to finish php first and then execute ajax. i think your sugestion more save time to execute code

Comment: i suggest this, because code will be more rehusable, and more potent for debug